# aws-sdk-go-v2 api error InvalidPart: One or more of the specified parts could not be found

Tags: go, aws-sdk-go-v2

So I tried to upload multiple part using AWS, but I got `One or more of the specified parts could not be found. The part may not have been uploaded, or the specified entity tag may not match the part's entity tag.` when doing `CompleteMultipartUpload`, anyone know which part that are not correct?

- Even when I removed all `ChecksumAlgorithm` and `ChecksumSHA256` part it still have the same error.
- Even when I set `ContentLength` and used different size >5MB (so it gives different etag using `strings.Repeat`), it still give the same un-unseful error.

Normal put/get request without multipart works fine.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    _ "embed"
    "encoding/json"
    "strings"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3/types"
    "github.com/kokizzu/gotro/L"
)

//go:embed secret.json
var secret []byte

type Cfg struct {
    Url       string `json:"url"`
    AccessKey string `json:"accessKey"`
    SecretKey string `json:"secretKey"`
}

const helloWorld = "Hello world\n123\n"

func main() {
    var jsonCfg Cfg

    err := json.Unmarshal(secret, &jsonCfg)
    L.PanicIf(err, `secret.json parsing failed`)

    ctx := context.Background()
    cred := credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider(jsonCfg.AccessKey, jsonCfg.SecretKey, "")
    awsCfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx, config.WithCredentialsProvider(cred), config.WithRegion(`us-west-2`))
    L.PanicIf(err, `failed config.LoadDefaultConfig`)
    s3Client := s3.NewFromConfig(awsCfg)
    typ := types.ChecksumAlgorithmSha256

    {
        bucket := aws.String(`testbucket-054803077`)
        key := aws.String(`multipart` + string(typ))
        out, err := s3Client.CreateMultipartUpload(ctx, &s3.CreateMultipartUploadInput{
            Bucket:            bucket,
            Key:               key,
            ChecksumAlgorithm: typ, // not case sensitive
        })
        L.PanicIf(err, `failed s3Client.CreateMultipartUpload`)
        L.Describe(out)

        part, err := s3Client.UploadPart(ctx, &s3.UploadPartInput{
            Bucket:            bucket,
            Key:               key,
            UploadId:          out.UploadId,
            PartNumber:        2,
            ChecksumAlgorithm: typ,
            Body:              strings.NewReader(helloWorld),
        })
        L.PanicIf(err, `failed s3Client.UploadPart 1`)
        L.Describe(part)
        p1 := types.CompletedPart{
            ETag:       part.ETag,
            PartNumber: 1,
            //ChecksumCRC32:  part.ChecksumCRC32,
            //ChecksumCRC32C: part.ChecksumCRC32C,
            ChecksumSHA256: part.ChecksumSHA256,
            //ChecksumSHA1:   part.ChecksumSHA1,
        }

        part2, err := s3Client.UploadPart(ctx, &s3.UploadPartInput{
            Bucket:            bucket,
            Key:               key,
            UploadId:          out.UploadId,
            PartNumber:        2,
            ChecksumAlgorithm: typ,
            Body:              strings.NewReader(helloWorld),
        })
        L.PanicIf(err, `failed s3Client.UploadPart 2`)
        L.Describe(part2)
        p2 := types.CompletedPart{
            ETag:       part2.ETag,
            PartNumber: 2,
            //ChecksumCRC32:  part2.ChecksumCRC32,
            //ChecksumCRC32C: part2.ChecksumCRC32C,
            ChecksumSHA256: part2.ChecksumSHA256,
            //ChecksumSHA1:   part2.ChecksumSHA1,
        }

        final, err := s3Client.CompleteMultipartUpload(ctx, &s3.CompleteMultipartUploadInput{
            Bucket:   bucket,
            Key:      key,
            UploadId: out.UploadId,
            MultipartUpload: &types.CompletedMultipartUpload{
                Parts: []types.CompletedPart{
                    p1,
                    p2,
                },
            },
        })
        L.PanicIf(err, `failed s3Client.CompleteMultipartUpload`)
        L.Describe(final)
    }

}
```

the go mod file

```
module checksum1

go 1.20

require (
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config v1.18.15
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3 v1.30.5
    github.com/kokizzu/gotro v1.2612.246
)

require (
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2 v1.17.5 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/protocol/eventstream v1.4.10 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials v1.13.15 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/ec2/imds v1.12.23 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/internal/configsources v1.1.29 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/internal/endpoints/v2 v2.4.23 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/internal/ini v1.3.30 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/internal/v4a v1.0.21 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/internal/accept-encoding v1.9.11 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/internal/checksum v1.1.24 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/internal/presigned-url v1.9.23 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/internal/s3shared v1.13.23 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sso v1.12.4 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ssooidc v1.14.4 // indirect
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sts v1.18.5 // indirect
    github.com/aws/smithy-go v1.13.5 // indirect
    github.com/fatih/color v1.14.1 // indirect
    github.com/kr/pretty v0.3.1 // indirect
    github.com/kr/text v0.2.0 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.1.13 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.17 // indirect
    github.com/op/go-logging v0.0.0-20160315200505-970db520ece7 // indirect
    github.com/rogpeppe/go-internal v1.9.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.5.0 // indirect
)
```

the `secret.json`:

```json
{ "url": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443",
   "accessKey": "xxx",
   "secretKey": "xxx",
}
```

make sure the bucket already exists and writable.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind `PartNumber` first part is typo, should be 1 not 2.

then the error will be `api error EntityTooSmall: Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size`, so it should be >5MB